# How to make difference of two sum queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to calculate goals difference of soccer teams. 
basically it is: 
(goalsScoredAtHome + goalsScoredAway) - (goalsConciededAtHome + goalsConciededAway) 
Everything is saved in one table:

```
homeTeam | awayTeam | goalsHome | goalsAway
  USA    |  Poland  |     2     |    0
 Poland  |   USA    |     3     |    1
```

this is what I have as 4 separate queries:

```
(select sum(goalsHome) as GoalsScoredHome from game where home = 'USA' 
+
select sum(goalsAway) as GoalsScoredAway from game where away = 'USA')
-
(select sum(goalsAway) as GoalsConciededHome from game where home = 'USA'
+
select sum(goalsHome) as GoalsConciededAway from game where away = 'USA')
```

Is there any way to do it in one query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct translation of your query uses conditional aggregation:

```
select (sum(case when home = 'USA' then goalsHome else 0 end) +
        sum(case when away = 'USA' then goalsAway else 0 end)
       ) -
       (sum(case when home = 'USA' then goalsAway else 0 end) +
        sum(case when away = 'USA' then goalsHome else 0 end)
       )
from game;
```

You can simplify this to:

```
select (sum(case when home = 'USA' then goalsHome - goalsAway else 0 end) +
        sum(case when away = 'USA' then goalsAway - goalsHome else 0 end)
       )
from game;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like the following

```
select sum(gs-gs) as GoalScore from(
  select sum(GoalsScore1) as gs from (
    select sum(goalsHome) as GoalsScore1 from game where homeTeam = 'USA' union all select sum(goalsAway) as GoalsScore1 from game where awayTeam = 'USA'
  )gs1 union all
  select sum(GoalsScore2) as gs from (
    select sum(goalsHome) as GoalsScore2 from game where homeTeam = 'USA' union all select sum(goalsAway) as GoalsScore2 from game where awayTeam = 'USA'
  )gs2
)gs3
```